# Update record with EF in one table, with concurrency check on another table

Tags: entity-framework

I need to perform update on a record in one table, but whether this update is allowed depends on value of record in another table. I can download two entities, check them, change value and save.

So far, so good, but I have to make sure, that between checking and saving my "allowing" record won't change. Basically I need something like concurrency handling, but not on the changed record.

Entity Framework case. I prefer to do not switch to procedures or SQL if possible.

My scenario.

```
var db = new MyDb();
var allowingRecord = db.AllowingRecords.First();

if(allowingRecord.Allow) // allows to make changes in RecordsToChange
{
    var recordToChange = db.RecordsToChange.First();
    recordToChange.FieldToChange = "Changing";
}

// Somwhere right here allowingRecord.Allow changes to false, but entity is not updated

db.SaveChanges();
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Memento design pattern for this purpose. Its basically store your state and you can use it always with that pattern
For example you can check this link it has code example as well;
http://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern